Python try/except not stopping errors
My following code was designed to handle exceptions and switch serialport if nothing was found.
try:
    serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-10'
except:
    try: 
        serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'
    except:
        print("Unable to find sensor. Try again")

However, it is not actually handling exceptions, and still lets them get through to the console:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 322, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/cu.usbserial-10'

I have set it in the code so that if there is no /dev/cu.usbserial-10, it tries serial-110, and if that's not there, it prints something, but it does not print ever.
Edit:
I am using pyserial so the serial_port assignment attempts to find a file location. '/dev/cu.usbserial-10' is one of the USB ports on my computer.
The error does show that its at line 322, but my file is not >100 lines long.
More context:
import serial

serial_port = 0

try:
    serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-10'
except:
    try:
        serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'
    except:
        print("no")


baud_rate = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate) # serial data, non-usable

try:
    while True:
        rawdata = ser.readline().decode().strip() # raw string data from serial
        print(rawdata)

This is quite literally my whole file, and when usbserial-10 is found, it does work.

In the posted code, the only line of code that is actually inside the try/except block is a simple string assignment, which cannot possibly fail.  The line of code given in the error message is certainly NOT in the try/excpt block.

The code you showed us only binds strings to a variable named serial_port. Such assignments never raise an exception. What you didn't show us is any code that tries to open a port.

I added some information to help

Please include more relevant code. As said by @JohnGordon, you're only showing us a string assignment. We can't help this issue without the code that is actually causing the error

Show us the code that actually OPENS the serial port.  You have only shown us the code that assigns the NAME of the serial port.

As a side-note: Limit your exceptions to OSError at the very least; catching bare except: will catch any exception, including stuff it makes zero sense to catch blindly and handle like any other exception (e.g. the user hitting Ctrl-C to kill the program).

sorry everyone, i did add more relevant code

@ShadowRanger thats fine if it catches all the errors

@CheezGuy: except OSError: would catch all the errors that are reasonable to catch from system calls (which includes just about every interaction with the file system and I/O layers).

@CheezGuy: You just edited in the line calling serial.Serial with zero context. We need a [MCVE] to determine if you actually put it in a try block. Which you almost certainly didn't, given your error. Copy in all the code necessary to reproduce your problem (and no more).

@ShadowRanger I added more context/code that was not there earlier.

ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate) This line is not inside a try/except block at all.  Why did you think it was?

@JohnGordon that line was to get serial data, the try except block was for trying the usb ports

according to the posted code you're trying to execute some kind of function that opens a serial port according to the assigned text.
try:
serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-10' 
    #you're only assigning the value to a variable . you actually need to call the function that youre testing with that variable here
except:
    try: 
        serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'
    except:
        print("Unable to find sensor. Try again")

here is a sample code:
try:
serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-10'
response=open_serial_port(serial_port) #assuming 'open_serial_port' is the function name.
except:
    try: 
        serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'
        response=open_serial_port(serial_port) #assuming 'open_serial_port' is the function name.
    except:
        print("Unable to find sensor. Try again")

this is an example of how you an fix it.
here is the updated code you provided:
import serial

serial_port = 0
baud_rate = 115200

try:
    serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-10'
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate) # serial data, non-usable
except:
    try:
        serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'
        ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate) # serial data, non-usable
    except:
        print("no")

try:
    while True:
        rawdata = ser.readline().decode().strip() # raw string data from serial
        print(rawdata)

except:
    pass


i added more code later on in the post. have a look at that because i am not opening a serial port, I am printing the contents of it.

i updated the ans. do let me know if it works out.
import serial
serial_port = 0
baud_rate = 115200
serial_port = ['/dev/cu.usbserial-10','/dev/cu.usbserial-110']
for i in serial_port:
try:
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)
if ser:
break
except:
pass
rawdata = ser.readline().decode().strip()
print(rawdata) 
you can write the code in this manner as well

Thanks it worked! (i also tried the same thing before seeing this, but this was the answer)

You didn't wrap the opening of the port in try/except, and that's what's erroring. String assignment is essentially infallible, no exceptions will ever occur there. An idiomatic way to achieve your goal would be to replace:
import serial

serial_port = 0

try:
    serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-10'
except:
    try:
        serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'
    except:
        print("no")


baud_rate = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate) # serial data, non-usable

with:
import serial
import sys

baud_rate = 115200

# Loop over possible ports until we open one successfully, or all fail
for serial_port in ('/dev/cu.usbserial-10', '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'):
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)
        break  # If opening the serial port succeeded, we're done, move on to using it
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Failed to open {serial_port!r}", file=sys.stderr)
else:
    sys.exit(f"Couldn't not open any serial ports, exiting...")

try:
    while True:
        rawdata = ser.readline().decode().strip() # raw string data from serial
        print(rawdata)
except OSError:
    # Handle errors as desired

